# VB.NET | EMF File becomes plain white in crystal report, How to properly save emf file in sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

After successfully converted a png file to emf file, another problem begins because when I tried to display the emf file in crystal report it became white.

[image]

The emf file was fetched in SQL Server.

I tried to export the data into the database, I found out that the emf file is blank. but I am pretty sure that the emf file I saved is not blank. so the main question is how to properly save an emf file in the database (SQL Server).

here is my code to save the image.

```
Dim SqlCom As SqlCommand
Dim imageData As Byte()
Dim sFileName As String
Dim qry As String
Try 
    If jonsqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
       jonsqlcon.Open()
    End If
       imageData = ReadFile(sFilePath)
       sFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sFilePath)
       qry = "INSERT INTO Signature (ControlNo,Sig) " & _
       "VALUES(@ControlNo,@Sig)"

       SqlCom = New SqlCommand(qry, jonsqlcon) 
       SqlCom.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ControlNo", TxtControlNo.Text))
       SqlCom.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Sig", DirectCast(imageData, Object)))

       SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())

    End Try
```

and here is the `ReadFile` Function

```
Private Function ReadFile(ByVal sPath As String) As Byte()
    Dim data As Byte() = Nothing
    Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(sPath)
    Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length
    Dim fStream As New FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim br As New BinaryReader(fStream)
    data = br.ReadBytes(CInt(numBytes))

    Return data
End Function
```

Comment: You don't seem to be specifying (Sql)DbTypes in your `New SqlParameter` calls. What actually gets saved into Sig in the database? It's likely the text `System.Object`. Refer to the [SqlParameter constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.-ctor) that include `SqlDbType` parameters.

Comment: What's the data type of the `Signature.Sig` column? If you're trying to store binary file data in there it should be `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: the data type is image

Comment: The `image`, `text` and `ntext` data types have been deprecated since at least SQL Server 2005. Ref: [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) _IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead._